# How to get list of Azure VMs (non-classic/Resource Managed) using Java API

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-java-sdk

How to get list of VMs (non-classic) using Java API, which are created using resource Manager? Why we need tenant id, client id and client key to create 'com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.ComputeManagementClient' object?

Can it be done using subscription id and Azure Portal credentials?
Sample provided with azure-mgmt-compute project needs these tenant id, client id where as we don't need these details when we create VM (selecting Resource Manager) on Azure Portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why we need tenant id, client id and client key to create
>   'com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.ComputeManagementClient'
>   object?

Behind the scenes, `com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.ComputeManagementClient` consumes `Azure Resource Manager (ARM) REST API` for performing Virtual Machines related operations. `ARM API` makes use of `Azure Active Directory (AD)` for authentication and authorization. In order to use `Azure AD` for this purpose, you would need to create an application in your `Azure AD` and grant that application permission to execute `Azure Service Management API`. You would need `Tenant Id`, `Client Id` and other things for that purpose only. So a user uses your application by allowing the application to be installed in their `Azure AD`. `Tenant Id` is the unique id of your application in your user's Azure AD. `Client Id` is the unique id of your application.

Once everything's been setup properly, in order to use the library user is authenticated against their Azure AD. As a part of authentication/authorization flow, user gets a token and this library makes use of this token to make authenticated request against ARM API to manage Virtual Machines.

> Can it be done using subscription id and Azure Portal credentials?
>   Sample provided with azure-mgmt-compute project needs these tenant id,
>   client id where as we don't need these details when we create VM
>   (selecting Resource Manager) on Azure Portal.

If you notice, you would first need to login into Azure Portal using your Microsoft account or Work/School account. Portal software fetches the token as a part of the login process. After that it makes use of tenant id, client id and this token to perform all operations. So essentially it is doing the same thing however it is not visible to you.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for your detailed reply. When you say "In order to use Azure AD for this purpose, you would need to create an application in your Azure AD and grant that application permission to execute Azure Service Management API." will this same application will be used to fetch all VMs (created using Resource Manager)? And though it will be created by any account under that single subscription?

Comment: `will this same application will be used to fetch all VMs (created using Resource Manager)?` --> Yes. `And though it will be created by any account under that single subscription?` --> I am not sure I understand this. Would you mind explaining.

Comment: Thanks again Gaurav!  I meant, we can create users under AD and if these users can create VMs using resource manager, can this single application created under AD will fetch the VMs created by those all users?

Comment: Simple answer is "Yes" because all the Virtual Machines are created in same Azure Subscription. A somewhat complicated answer is "Depends". It depends on the permission the logged in user has on the Azure Resources in that Subscription (RBAC). When listing Virtual Machines, a user would only be able to see the VMs she/he has access to (please don't confuse access with create; a user may have access to other VMs as well). I would recommend reading up (or post another question) on Azure RBAC.

Comment: Thanks again Gaurav.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @GauravMantri explaination in detail.

> How to get list of VMs (non-classic) using Java API, which are created using resource Manager?

According to the Azure Reference for [Virtual Machine REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163647.aspx), you can get the list of all VMs in a resource group using [the REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163572.aspx) that need to [authenticate Azure Resource Manager requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx) in the [common parameters and headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163630.aspx#bk_common).

Here is the sample code using Java API as below.

```
// The parameters include clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, subscriptionId and resourceGroupName.
private static final String clientId = "<client-id>";
private static final String clientSecret = "<key>";
private static final String tenantId = "<tenant-id>";
private static final String subscriptionId = "<subscription-id>";
private static final String resouceGroupName = "<resource-group-name>";

// The function for getting the access token via Class AuthenticationResult
private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromServicePrincipalCredentials()
        throws ServiceUnavailableException, MalformedURLException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    AuthenticationContext context;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        // TODO: add your tenant id
        context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId, false, service);
        // TODO: add your client id and client secret
        ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", cred, null);
        result = future.get();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    if (result == null) {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
    }
    return result;
}

// The process for getting the list of VMs in a resource group
Configuration config = ManagementConfiguration.configure(null, new URI("https://management.core.windows.net"),
        subscriptionId,
        getAccessTokenFromServicePrincipalCredentials().getAccessToken());
ComputeManagementClient client = ComputeManagementService.create(config);
VirtualMachineListResponse listResponse = client.getVirtualMachinesOperations().list(resourceGroupName);
ArrayList<VirtualMachine> list = listResponse.getVirtualMachines();
```