# How to list Azure vms using python?

Tags: python, azure, listview, azure-vm-templates

I am trying to list Azure VMs using python code. could someone help me with this issue?

I have already tried to go through the code on the Microsoft website but it is not clear to me.

Comment: Hello Khalid and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a very good question for this site, we're about fixing broken code, not so much about helping you read the documentation.  Here is a handy post that can help you ask better questions in the future here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello Hoog, Thank you for the welcoming and the feedback. I am here to learn and I will get better on how to ask a question. Thanks again for your comment :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I list Azure Virtual Machines using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925397/how-could-i-list-azure-virtual-machines-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to follow the section [`Register your client application with Azure AD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad) of Azure offical document `Azure REST API Reference` to register an application with Azure AD on Azure portal for getting the required parameters `client_id` and `secret` for Authentication to list VMs.

And, you continue to get the other required parameters `subscription_id` and `tenant_id`.

Then, to create a virtual environment in Python to install Azure SDK for Python via `pip install azure` or just install Azure Compute Management for Python via `pip install azure-mgmt-compute`.

Here is my sample code.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id='<your client id>',
    secret='<your client secret>',
    tenant='<your tenant id>'
)

subscription_id = '<your subscription id>'
client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
```

If just list VMs by resource group, to use function [`list(resource_group_name, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-python/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.operations.html#azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.operations.VirtualMachinesOperations.list) as the code below.

```
resource_group_name = '<your resource group name>'
vms_by_resource_group = client.virtual_machines.list(resource_group_name)
```

Or you want to list all VMs in your subscription, to use function [`list_all(custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-python/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.operations.html#azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.operations.VirtualMachinesOperations.list_all) as the code below.

```
all_vms = client.virtual_machines.list_all()
```

As references, there are two SO threads I think which may help for understanding deeper: [How to get list of Azure VMs (non-classic/Resource Managed) using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178842/how-to-get-list-of-azure-vms-non-classic-resource-managed-using-java-api/36215834#36215834) and [Is it anyway to get ftpsState of azure web app (Azure Function app) using Python SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660811/is-it-anyway-to-get-ftpsstate-of-azure-web-app-azure-function-app-using-python/56682463#56682463).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was very helpful.