# Azure Python SDK - list VMs and generate custom JSON response

Tags: python, json, azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

From the az cli I have a cmd to find all the VMs that are running and it returns all the info as a JSON file with keys that **I** define.

My question is how can I do this using the Python SDK? I would like the same key/value in a JSON format. I am doing some post processing in Python so I prefer to use Python from start to finish to generate the info.

working code below:

```
az vm list -d -o json --query `
    "[?powerState=='VM running'].{Name:name, admin:osProfile.adminUsername, STATUS:powerState RG:resourceGroup TAGS:tags}"
```

which returns

```
[
 {
    "Name": "boston",
    "RG": "r_group",
    "STATUS": "VM running",
    "TAGS": {
      "tag_1": "tag_value_1",
      "tag_2": "tag_value_2"
    },
    "admin": "waldo"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Code to list the VMS,

```
import azure.mgmt.compute as Compute
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile

import retry
import sys
import logging

@retry.retry(RuntimeError, tries=2)
def listVMs(resourceGroup):

    VM = get_client_from_cli_profile(Compute.ComputeManagementClient)

    try:
        VMs = VM.virtual_machines.list(resourceGroup)
        for vm in VMs:
            print(vm)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)

resourceGroup = sys.argv[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listVMs(resourceGroup)

else:
    print('Running as imported module')
    listVMs(resourceGroup)
```

Comment: thanks for the start but the custom json is just as important for me.

Comment: you need to organize with the logic. SO is not providing coding service

Answer (score 1):

In the end I was able to figure it with the help of a colleague and lots of searches. Posting this here in the hope that others will benefit from the answer.

Greets to [@Charles Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9773937/charles-xu) for getting me started with this answer [how-could-i-list-azure-virtual-machines-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925397/how-could-i-list-azure-virtual-machines-using-python)

It was difficult for me to find specific and relevant documentation from MS to address my issue.

**NOTE:** THis is a work in progress and I am sure that there is lots of room for improvement. I don't think the resulting json is perfect but json2html isn't complaining.

And now for the code....

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
import json
from json2html import *

# Tenant ID for your Azure subscription
TENANT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# Your service principal App ID
CLIENT = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# Your service principal password
KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# Your Azure Subscription ID
subscription_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=CLIENT,
    secret=KEY,
    tenant=TENANT_ID
)

result = []

# Create a Resource Management client
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()
for vm in vm_list:
    resource_group = vm.id.split("/")[4]
    vm_name = vm.name
    details = compute_client.virtual_machines.instance_view(resource_group, vm_name, expand='instanceView')

    status = len(details.statuses) >= 2 and details.statuses[1]
    if status and status.code == 'PowerState/running':
        tagz = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group, vm_name).tags
        if not tagz:
            tagz = ""
        admin = ''
        if hasattr(details, 'os_profile'):
            admin = details.os_profile.admin_username
        row = {"ComputerName": vm_name, "ResourceGroup": resource_group, "Admin": admin,
               "Status": status.code, "Tags": tagz}
        result.append(row)

data = json.dumps(result)
html = json2html.convert(json=data)
print(html)
```