# How to convert class type to string python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I have this `code` that prints information related to `VM`. The `output` is in the `class type`. How can I `convert` it to a form so that I can understand it?

```
 from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
 from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
    
 credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='XXXX',
                                          secret='XXXX', tenant='XXXX')
 compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
     credential, 'XXXX')
 for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
     print(vm.storage_profile)
```

I am getting `output` in the form. It is showing the `class` `type` of this `output`

> <'azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.models.storage_profile_py3.StorageProfile'>

Comment: Try `print(vm.storage_profile.as_dict())`. The method seems to be defined for its parent class, and that might get you something more readable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I list Azure Virtual Machines using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925397/how-could-i-list-azure-virtual-machines-using-python)

Comment: Hey @Hassan Turi, had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

It was printing `class` type because you are directly calling the `variable` without converting it. To do that You can create a new variable and assign the conversion to it and print that new variable. Or you can use directly in print statement as below,

Which is suggested by @*baileythegreen* as well,Thank you for your valuable insights posting the same in answer to help other community members.

***CODE:***

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
    
 credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='XXXX',
                                          secret='XXXX', tenant='XXXX')
 compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
     credential, 'XXXX')
 for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all():
     print(vm.storage_profile.as_dict())
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

***SO THREAD:*** [***Azure Python SDK - list VMs and generate custom JSON response***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827783/azure-python-sdk-list-vms-and-generate-custom-json-response)

***MS Q&A:-*** [***Printing list of Virtual Machines***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/660693/printing-list-of-virtual-machines.html)