# Equivalent service for AWS Lambda in Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, boto3

To get detailed info of ec2 instance via python in AWS, we can create a lambda function and use describe-instances boto3 api to fetch the results.

I'm looking for similar solution in Azure.
To get VM information via python in azure. Kindly share the APIs like boto3 and services to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Boto3 (AWS SDK for Python) -> [Azure SDK for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-overview)

AWS Lambda (serverless functions) -> [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview)

I also suggest reviewing the [Azure for AWS professionals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent describe instances on AWS boto SDK in Azure is

`list_all()/list()` at ComputeManagementClient.virtual_machines

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-compute-v2019-07-01-operations-virtualmachinesoperations-list-all

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58926524/5589820) example.